# bootstrap responsive two column issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on bootstrap framework. I have a query on bootstrap grid columns. In single row I need two column one should be in left and other should be in right with custom fields. It was working perfectly on col-lg i am giving pull-left and pull-right but when I reduced for Responsive it was not coming single row it was coming down.

Here is my code

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 pull-left timer">
                Timer
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 pull-right timer">
                Timer
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here are the css reference style i am using

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">

.timer{
background-color: #e2e2e2;
border: 1px solid #a1a1a1;
padding: 10px 40px; 
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
margin: 5px;
clear: both;
width:70px;
height:15px;
border-radius: 15px;
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
white-space: nowrap;
```

}

**Kindly help me where I am doing wrong**

Thanks
Mahadevan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing pull-left and pull-right first.  Make sure you don't have any other CSS interfering with your layout.

Doesn't look like the CSS class .timer is actually applying to anything, either, just FYI.

Comment: If i removed the pull-right and pull-left it was coming one below the other in large screen itself

Comment: Oh, I somehow missed the "timer" at the end of those.  Yeah, probably your margin, padding, width, clear, or (maybe) white-space attributes are causing that problem.

Comment: You need to sort of step back and let bootstrap handle the layout - or do it from scratch without the bootstrap classes.  Rule of thumb.

Answer (score 0):

Your codes for responsive layout is wrong

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                Timer
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                Timer
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And I suggest you don't use the class timer because that is where the issue starts, the `col-sm-*` class is used for small screens so it will work only on mobiles in-order to make the layout in the big screens you can use `col-md-*`

you can find more information in [bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

OR you can use this tool found online to make the [bootstrap grids](http://shoelace.io/)

Comment: hi Sujay,

Thanks for the Shoelace tool it was too good but I want custom for my page how to do ?

Comment: I did not understand what your question was, can you please re-phrase? and if you like my post you can give an up vote :D

Comment: Sorry for that i have click the TIck .  My question was I have to use Bootstrap responsive and I want to create two custom element like rounded corner one is left and other one should be in right of that page when I reduce the page to mobile it has to show the correct look and feel.